# universal analytics external js

Tags: ruby-on-rails, universal-analytics

I'm trying to use one external js file to track pageviews by using Universal Analytics. Here are my code:

```
class @GoogleAnalytics

 @load: ->
  ((i,s,o,g,r,a,m) ->
   i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r
   i[r] = i[r] || (->
    (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments))
   i[r].l = 1 * new Date()
   a = s.createElement(o)
   m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0]
   a.async = 1
   a.src = g
   m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  )(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga')

 ga('create', 'UA-56740029-1', 'auto')
 document.addEventListener "page:change", (->
   GoogleAnalytics.trackPageview()
 ), true

 @trackPageview: (url) ->
  if url
    ga('send', 'pageview', url)
  else
    ga('send', 'pageview')

 GoogleAnalytics.load()
```

This code is not tracking the pageview correctly, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @NickM Before this I was using ga.js, and I was using the template in [link](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-google-analytics.html). I am trying to modify it to work with universal analytics. I assume this js file will execute every time this is a change in the page

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something like the link in your comment you have to add this to your application.html.erb file inside the  tag:

```
<script>
  GoogleAnalytics.load();
</script>
```

And remove the last line from the Coffeescript example in your question.

Comment: Is that possible to do something like [this one](http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/google_analytics.html)

Comment: See the edit to my answer. The issue is that you still have to call the function within your app.